# Detect what raises an exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I made a Python 2.7.9 script which downloads some photos from the web using `urllib.urlretrieve`. I made a simple error dictation using the `try` and `except` commands, like so:

```
try:
    urllib.urlretrieve("http://example.com/image.jpg", "1.jpg")
except IOError:
    print "Could not connect to 'example.com'!"
```

However, I realized that `IOError` could be also raised when no space left on the the harddrive. I want to detect what cause the raise of the IOError (could not connect to example.com/no space left), and display the correct error message.

How can I do so? Thanks!

Comment: there is no error raised if the file does not exist so you cannot catch all errors

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Im not sure I understood what you meant, can you please explain it again? Thanks.

Comment: try `urllib.urlretrieve("http://example.com/image.foobar", "1.jpg")`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It saved a file to the current working directory called `1.jpg` which include the HTML code in http://example.com/image.foobar...

Comment: yes but the files is not actually from the website because there is no image.foobar there.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham But it will raise error if the return code won't be 200 as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As zoosuck said, you could differentiate between errors with more than one except-Statement. If you want to differentiate between IOErrors, take a look at the documentation of IOError. It reveals that IOError has an attribute "errno". You can use the errno module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html) to identify the cause:

```
import urllib
import errno

try: 
    urllib.urlretrieve("http://example.com/image.jpg", "1.jpg")     
except IOError, e:
    if e.errno == errno.ENOSPC:
        print "No space left on device"
    else:
        print "Could not connect to 'example.com'!"
```

Comment: Also, errno.ENOSPC is 28, so you can just use `if e.errno == 28` instead.